# Modular 3rd party widget in react and webpack 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, webpack-2

I am trying to develop a 3rd party widget that other websites would be able to use. I have already built a web app with **react/webpack2** but it works as an actual website.

I am struggling to achieve it working as a widget. My goal would be to have different modules loaded in different pages by setting a param in the main widget element like so:

- **Page 1:** `<my-widget module="module1" additional-param="param">`
- **Page 2:** `<my-widget module="module2" additional-param="param">`

Any examples or best practices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you can achieve this through

```
<My-widget children={ ({ param }) => (<Module1 { ...param } /> } />
```

using children as props will work just like `<My-Widget><Module1 /><My-Widget>`